# How to programmatically add constraints from label to UICollectionViewCell?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, constraints, uicollectionviewcell

I have a question regarding constraints to a UICollectionViewCell.

An image is included to help visualize what I mean.

I have a UICollectionViewController. Inside this controller I have added a UICollectionViewCell, which only takes up a part of the screen.

My question is: How do I add constraints from a label (see image) to that UICollectionViewCell, such that I know that the label is always the same distance from the UICollectionViewCell. In the image the distance is shown as an arrow (this is the constraint, that I want to add).

[image]

Hope someone can help me out.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not doing it in Storyboard/Xibs? It might help you understand how constraints works, and then look how to replicate it programmatically.

Comment: I like the control I have, when doing it programmatically. I started out using storyboards, and then went away from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the label is a subview from the `CollectionViewController`, it can be done like:

```
label.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: cell.bottomAnchor, constant: someConstant).isActive = true
```

The above code works for me at least with an `UITableViewController` and its cells, so it should also work with a `UICollectionView`.

Comment: P.S. There are many ways to declare the constraints, but this is the best in my opinion.

Comment: But how do you target the cell? Where does that come from? In my collectionviewcontroller, the cells are made in a func. I cant not target mmy cell from the viewDidLoad method.

Comment: Inside the function you create the cell, you can add the constraint. I suppose you are creating the cell inside `collectionView(_:, cellForItemAt:)`, right?... Anyway, if you are not using that method and adding the constraint in the same method the cell is created is not viable; then, you can save a reference to your cell and add the constraint in `viewDidLayoutSubviews()` or in `updateViewConstraints`. If that does not work, maybe update the question with the code where you are loading the cell.

Comment: When i try to add the constraint in that method, it gives me the following error: 'Unable to activate constraint with anchors <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600001f56200 "UILabel:0x7f8a6670e930'test label'.top"> and <NSLayoutYAxisAnchor:0x600001f56280 "app.CustomCollectionViewCell:0x7f8a6661ba80.bottom"> because they have no common ancestor.

Comment: That means that your label and the cell are not in the same view. To which view are you adding the label as a subview?

Comment: To the CollectionViewController, in which the cell should be added, if understand the method correctly

Comment: Yes, sorry, my bad!! It does not work in `collectionView(_:, cellForItemAt:)` because the cell has not been added yet. You can use `collectionView(_:willDisplay:forItemAt:)` instead. Or the other two methods I mentioned above. I have already created a demo project and it works.

Comment: This was exactly, what I was looking for ! Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

First at all you should know what constraints you have to set.
In this case I guess it is top, trailing and leading if you want an infinite label. Else you have to set height constraint too.

Example of code for adding constraints for label in collectionViewCell:

```
    label = UILabel()
    self.addSubview(label)

    label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    // creating a top constraint related to cell content view top with constant 16
    let topConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .top, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 16)
    let leadingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .leading, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: .leading, multiplier: 1, constant: 16)
    let trailingConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .trailing, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: self, attribute: .trailing, multiplier: 1, constant: 16)

    // optional constraint
    //let heightConstaint = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .height, relatedBy: NSLayoutConstraint.Relation.equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: 44)

    self.addConstraints([topConstraint, leadingConstraint, trailingConstraint])
```

---

If I understood your question right, you want to have similar relations between your collectionView and label.

So you should write the same code as I wrote above but relate your label constraints to collectionView.

[image: collectionView constraints]

[image: label constraints]

Comment: But this is not adding a constraint between the label and the cell right? I want to set the constraint in the collectionviewcontroller, where I cant target the cell (or i think i cant).

Comment: hmmm, you can use footer view for this.

Comment: Adding a label below the collectionViewCell in a collectionView hierarchy is a bad practice. And I guess even unreal 'cuz u cant relate your label to reusable cell.

Comment: What would you suggest I do instead? What is good practice if I need a "sliding cards" view on the center of the screen, with free space above and below, such that i can add labels or buttons.

Comment: In which direction your cards should scroll? If it is horizontal you can set height constraint to your collectionView and relate label to this. Next time please clarify your task, it is har to understand all cases 'cuz we don't work with your project.

Comment: Thanks man! I'll remember to clarify it more next time. The direction is horizontal. Regarding your edit. Should I then add the collectionview into a new full height view, to fill out the screen height, and then add button/labels to this new view?

Comment: Yes, don't use "Collection View Controller". Use simple View Controller and add collectionView as subview. It will allow you to flexible change UI in screen. Since you add collectionView as subview you can relate any other UI element to this as you want.